# Android activity’s xml layout

Tags: c#, android, web, imageview, monodevelop

I am using MonoDevelop for Android and have a question about using Android Smart Image View. Here is the WWW address: http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/

The installation is as follows:

> Add a SmartImageView to your activity’s xml layout:

```
<com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
android:id="@+id/my_image" />
```

Can I place have some help to do this properly. I am not sure exactly where to place this code. I am currently using the StandardControls sample and the Gridview activity.

**EDIT**

I have added the SmartImageView to the xml layout file. When I code the following line:

```
SmartImageView myImage = (SmartImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
```

I am getting the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'SmartImageView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The installation says:

> Download the latest .jar file from github and place it in your Android app’s libs/ folder

I do not have a libs/ folder. Do I need to create a /libs folder? If so, where do I create this folder? Also, once I have this folder, do I extract the contents of the .jar file into the folder, or just place the .jar file into the folder?

Currently I have just extracted the .class files into a folder with the other .class files for this project. I am pretty sure this is what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Your Project in Eclipse

```
Project->res->layout->your_activity_layout.xml
```

Add a **SmartImageView** to your activity’s **your_activity_layout.xml** layout Like this:

```
<com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

**EDIT:**

Use this way in your Activity.

```
SmartImageView myImage = (SmartImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
```

Load an image into the view from a URL:

```
myImage.setImageUrl("http://www..../XYZ.jpg");
```

Comment: Dixit, can you please have a look at my edited question please?